# How to debug when vim writes random files

Tags: vim

I have a weird hard-to-localize issue with vim. It's almost certainly a weird custom configuration that is my fault, but I don't know (1) what I should be looking for and (2) how to reproduce it.  I don't know if anyone will be able to help, but its been plaguing me for years, so I thought I'd at least make a post about it.

The issue is that after using vim, I occasionally find weird files in the directories I was working. The file names were usually characters I was typing. I have absolutely no idea what is triggering this, and it doesn't happen that often, so its hard to simply comment out a piece of my vimrc check if it occurs and narrow it down that way.

Examples of the file names I get are:

```
= np.diff(bins)
ep='')
= {
(shape0, device=device"
_rect = cv2.undistortPoints(left_corners, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs)
elf.alt_fc = nh.layers.MultiLayerPerceptronNd(
=feat_dim, noli=swish,
hape0 = (
ys, ubelt
tates, evidence=evidence)
ample_input = torch_encoder_result
tack = kwimage.stack_images(imgs, axis=1, resize='smaller')
hear_range=(-10, 10)
```

There is nothing in common between the files names that I can see. The majority have an "=" and a paren, but not all. I really have no idea how to reproduce this error. I feel like I must have a habit of hitting an incorrect key stroke that causes this issue, or there is some plugin doing something weird, or I have a crazy configuration (which I do).

The contents of the files varies. Sometimes they look like git differences. The one from the first example was the page for "less --help" (yes I grepped for that). Another is what looks like a docstring for a python class (I'm not 100% sure if this only happens with Python files, because most of my vim usage is Python).

Any tips that anyone has for how to further debug this would be appreciated.

Just for reference this is my vimrc: https://github.com/Erotemic/local/blob/master/vim/portable_vimrc and it does reference and source several other files in that repo, so I don't expect anybody to be able to parse it and figure it out.

If I was to take a guess I'd say its probably an auto-commands that's doing it, and I do have all of those auto-commands defined in this file: https://github.com/Erotemic/local/blob/master/vim/rc_settings/autocommand_settings.vim  but I don't see anything that would cause this issue.

Comment: I guess the starting point would be for you to disable your vimrc and check whether the problem still happens or not. From your description, I guess it's possible the problem might not be in vim, but maybe in git configs or some other shell environment variable (less or lessopen perhaps?) If this problem happens often enough (weekly?) and you can manage to use Vim without your rcfile for a week or so and confirm the problem doesn't happen, then you'd have more evidence it's in Vim...

Comment: Sorry, but those rc files look way too over the top. I'm not surprised you'd find it hard to debug these issues, I mean looking at those they look almost impossible to debug. The one with the autocmd's, for the bulk of it, it would be much more straightforward to have a single `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` with your Python filetype settings, in direct plain Vim commands.